# How to draw this complicated graph in Latex?

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

[image]
I want to draw a graph. I do not know how to draw it. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: By use of the `pgfplots` package, where for axis you select `loglogaxis`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: You deleted the graph in the last edit. This makes the question seem quite... out of focus. It's OK to not want to have this specific image on the site, but it would be great if you could add a description of the graph you need, for instance: "a logarithmic graph with table like titles"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my approach. I tried to get the data points of the lines using [this online tool](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/) and did a potential fit usig Excel to get the functions. Then, I added the lines to the `loglog`-plot.
For the labels, you can use `\draw` in combination with `(axis cs:x,y)` to have them aligned using plot coordinates.

[image: loglog plot]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    log ticks with fixed point,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            name=plot,
            height=9cm,
            width=16cm,
            xmin=0.001,
            xmax=1000,
            ymin=0.001,
            ymax=100,
            tick style={draw=none},
            grid=both,
            clip=false,
            ]
            \addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.001:1000,
            ] 
            (\x,{0.1624*\x^0.6348});
            \addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.001:1000,
            ] 
            (\x,{1.4294*\x^0.4895});
            \addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.01:1000,
            ] 
            (\x,{0.5615*\x^0.5189});
            \addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.001:1000,
            ] 
            (\x,{5.7747*\x^0.3595});
            \addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.001:1000,
            ] 
            (\x,{20.062*\x^0.2214});
            
            \draw (axis cs:0.001,100) rectangle node {1} (axis cs:0.01,400);
            \draw (axis cs:0.01,100) rectangle node {2} (axis cs:0.1,400);
            \draw (axis cs:0.1,100) rectangle node {3} (axis cs:1,400);
            \draw (axis cs:1,100) rectangle node {4} (axis cs:4,400);
            \draw (axis cs:4,100) rectangle node {5} (axis cs:10,400);
            \draw (axis cs:10,100) rectangle node {6} (axis cs:40,400);
            \draw (axis cs:40,100) rectangle node {7} (axis cs:100,400);
            \draw (axis cs:100,100) rectangle node {8} (axis cs:400,400);
            \draw (axis cs:400,100) rectangle node {9} (axis cs:1000,400);
            
            \draw (axis cs:40,1) rectangle node {10} (axis cs:400,2);
        \end{loglogaxis}    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

I changed the code a bit to suit your needs.

[image: loglog v2]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    log ticks with fixed point,
}

\usepackage{contour}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            name=plot,
            height=10cm,
            width=20cm,
            xmin=0.001,
            xmax=1000,
            ymin=0.001,
            ymax=100,
            tick style={draw=none},
            xticklabel=\empty,
            yticklabel=\empty,
            yticklabel pos=left,
            extra x ticks={0.001,0.002,0.004,0.01,0.02,0.04,0.1,0.2,0.4,1,2,4,10,20,40,100,200,400,1000},
            extra x tick labels={0.001,0.002,0.004,0.01,0.02,0.04,0.1,0.2,0.4,1,2,4,10,20,40,100,200,400,1000},
            extra y ticks={1,2,3,5,10,20,30,50,100},
            extra y tick labels={1,2,3,5,10,20,30,50,100},
            grid=both,
            clip=false,
            ]
            \addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.001:1000,
            ] 
            (\x,{0.1624*\x^0.6348});
            \addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.01:1000,
            ]
            (\x,{0.5615*\x^0.5189});
            \addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.001:1000,
            ] 
            (\x,{1.4294*\x^0.4895});
            \addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.001:1000,
            ] 
            (\x,{5.7747*\x^0.3595});
            \addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.001:1000,
            ] 
            (\x,{20.062*\x^0.2214});
            
            \foreach \xa/\xb/\lab in {0.001/0.01/Lab1, 0.01/0.1/Lab2, 0.1/1/Lab3, 1/4/Lab4, 4/10/Lab5, 10/40/Lab6, 40/100/Lab7, 100/400/Lab8, 400/1000/Lab9}{%
                \edef\temp{%
                    \noexpand \draw (axis cs:\xa,100) rectangle node {\noexpand\contour{white}{\lab}} (axis cs:\xb,400);
                }\temp
            }
            
            \draw[lightgray] (axis cs:40,1) rectangle node[black] {\contour{white}{Lab10}} (axis cs:400,2);
            
            \foreach \y [count=\i from 1] in {30,40,60,90}{%
                \edef\temp{%
                    \noexpand \node[black,below right,font=\noexpand\tiny] at (axis cs:400,\y) {\noexpand\contour{white}{\i}};
                }\temp
            }
        \end{loglogaxis}
        
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            height=10cm,
            width=20cm,
            xmin=0.001,
            xmax=1000,
            ymin=0.001,
            ymax=100,
            tick style={draw=none},
            xticklabel=\empty,
            yticklabel=\empty,
            yticklabel pos=right,
            extra y ticks={1,2,3,5,10,20,30,50,100},
            extra y tick labels={1,2,3,5,10,20,30,50,100},
            yticklabel pos=right
            ]
        \end{loglogaxis}    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Your questions:

**Q1** *How the x-axis and y-axis numbers should be increased? I mean in original figure i have 1,2,3,5,10..... and in reality we have 0.01,0.1,1,10,100. I want to enter 1,2,3,5,10.... how should i do it? The x-axis numbers are on both side. How to put the numbers on both sides?*

I added some `extra y ticks` and `extra tick labels` and removed the other labels. The second axis can be generated with a dummy plot and `ylabel pos=right`.

**Q2** *In original figure we have numbers between inclined lines, how should I enter these numbers?*

You can add these numbers simply by adding nodes with labels to the graph using the `(axis cs:x pos,y pos)`. I thought of a looping approach using

```
\foreach \y [count=\i from 1] in {30,40,60,90}{%
                \edef\temp{%
                    \noexpand \node[black,below right,font=\noexpand\tiny] at (axis cs:400,\y) {\noexpand\contour{white}{\i}};
                }\temp
            }
```

Here `\y` are the y pos of the label and `\i` is the label. You can change this by copying the loop, change the y values, the x value and the `count from` command to the specific numbers.

Comment: Very very nice...+1.

Comment: The inclined lines are not at the same coordinate as depicted in main figure. 




\addplot[
            samples=500,
            domain=0.001:1000,
            ] 
            (\x,{0.1624*\x^0.6348});

Can you explain this code (\add plot.......) so that I can make that lines in a proper coordinate.

Comment: @Aqib `\addplot[samples=500, domain=0.001:1000, ] (\x,{0.1624*\x^0.6348})` means, that you plot the function `0.1624*\x^0.6348` for x values `0.001-1000`. If you want to change the line, you have to change the function you want to plot

Comment: How the x-axis and y-axis numbers should be increased? I mean in original figure i have 1,2,3,5,10..... and in reality we have 0.01,0.1,1,10,100. I want to enter 1,2,3,5,10.... how should i do it?
The x-axis numbers are on both side. How to put the numbers on both sides?

Comment: In original figure we have numbers between inclined lines, how should I enter these numbers?

Comment: @Aqib I edited my answer regarding your questions

Comment: How can I make the vertical line at point 0.01,0.1,1,4,10,40,100,400 to be more thicker than others?
Only specified point lines need to be thicker and darker.

Comment: @Aqib Just add `extra x tick style={major grid style={gray,line width=1pt}},` into your first 'axis' environment

Comment: Yes above command work.
But I want that some particular lines should be darker. I mean I want vertical line with number 0.01 to be darker and thicker but not 0.002 and 0.004. In the same way I want 0.1 to be darker and thicker and not 0.02 and 0.04.
So is there any way that I can make some particular vertical lines to be darker and thicker?

Comment: @Aqib If you don't need the tick labels at this position, you can remove them from the `extra x ticks` and `extra x tick labels`.

Answer (score 2):

A basic loglogaxis like in your picture done with `\pgfplots` (as suggested by @Zarko):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{log ticks with fixed point,}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            xlabel=A,ylabel=K,
            log basis x=10,
            log basis  y = 10,
            xmin=0.001, xmax=1000,
            ymin=0.001, ymax=100,           
            grid=both,
            x post scale=2, %switch this off if you do not want your x axis scaled
            ]

        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I add the text written at top in boxes? 
and how to include the inclined lines?